# Why is my site approximately 50% wider than viewport in IE and Edge?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

A site I'm preparing is about 150% width of the viewport. I have checked the site and no element appears to be wider than the viewport. The problem occurs only in IE 10+ and Edge; earlier versions of IE or other browsers display everything fine.

I have found out that:

- if I delete line 29 of the CSS (on CodePen) declaring width of `.branding-wrapper` the site is the correct size (but the .branding-wrapper must be as wide as the viewport. Changing width to 100vw does not result in any change.
- if I delete the media queries and line 9 of the CSS (justify-content:center) the site is the correct size (but the image must be centered)

```css
.test {
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 400px;
   background-color: red;
   margin-top: calc(100vh);
}
.header {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
}
.header-img {
   width: 2000px;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   z-index: -2;
}
@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
/* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
  .header-img{
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  .branding-wrapper {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
.branding-wrapper {
   height: 350px;
   width: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0px;
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<body class="home blog">
<div class="header">
    <img src="image link" alt="test" class="header-img">
    <div class="branding-wrapper ">
  text
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test"></div>
```

The problem can be seen here: 
https://codepen.io/mateuszcora/pen/WdOQMr

Comment: Not a complete fix, but try fooling around with max-width in some places. Or max-width *and* width, to control the...max-width.

Comment: Just by looking at your code, my guess would be that the `.header-img` styles are not properly set. A fixed `width: 2000px` is not what you really want. Is there any specific reason why you're using this width?

Comment: Yes -I need the image to have a minimum height. Setting it via width or min-width might be strange, but the point is that I don't want the image to scale with the site and I want the image to be centered. I know that in many cases only a part of the image will be shown, but that is what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: FYI Internet Explorer is a completely different browser from Edge. IE's last version was 11. Edge was built from scratch (more or less).

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue by centering the image another way in IE

```
.header {
    justify-content:center;
    display:flex;
}
   // margin-bottom:-52px;
}
.header-img {
    min-height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -2;
}

@media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
    /* IE10+ CSS styles go here */
    .header-img {
        transform:translateX(-50%);
        margin:0 auto;

    }
    .header{
        display:unset;
        justify-content:unset;
    }
```